# Save xhr.responseURL to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, xmlhttprequest-level2

I have an array of URLs that i need to find the redirects for.  I have been using XMLHttpRequest / xhr.responseURL to do so.  When I print the results to the console, the redirected URLs display as expected.  However, when I try to save those redirected URLs to an array, the array remains empty.  How can I save them to the array?

**Updated with code**

```
var imageDestinations = [];

function imageDestinationGrabber(imageSource) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', imageSource, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
    imageDestinations.push(xhr.responseURL).trim());
    console.log((xhr.responseURL).trim());
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The console log works, but the array remains empty.

Comment: you should post the relevant code

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of a problem but parentheses  at line `imageDestinations.push(xhr.responseURL).trim());` doesn't look right maybe it should be `imageDestinations.push(xhr.responseURL.trim());`

Answer (score 2):

You had a couple syntax issues that was breaking your code. You had an extra parenthesis at the end of your array push.

`imageDestinations.push(xhr.responseURL).trim());`

That is trying to `.trim()` the `.push()` call

Here's the fixed code:

```js
var imageDestinations = [];

function imageDestinationGrabber(imageSource) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', imageSource, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        imageDestinations.push( xhr.responseURL.trim() );
     console.log( xhr.responseURL.trim() );
 };
 xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I updated it, but i'm still running into the same issue.